# How to test while uploading a file using rspec in ruby (not rails)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I've tried a lot of stuff before coming here, I'm a beginner in Ruby. So, I have finished my final Proj. But, I can't find the way how I test the file uploading using RSpec in Ruby. Where ever I'm looking for it just show me about Rails.
The helper that I call in Post Model

```
class AttachmentHelper
def get_file(file)
    if file.nil?
        return ''
    else
        file_name = file[:filename]
        file = file[:tempfile]

        return false unless validate_file(file_name)

        mime = get_mime(file)

        upload_file(file, file_name, mime)
    end
end

def validate_file(file)
    raise "File Not allowed" if check_mime(file) == false
    true
end

def check_mime(file)
    mime_types = ['image/gif', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'video/mp4', 'application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-excel']

    mime = get_mime(file)

    return false unless mime_types.include?(mime)
    true
end

def get_mime(file)
    ext = File.extname(file)
    mime = Rack::Mime.mime_type(ext)
end

def upload_file(file, file_name, mime)
    filename = "#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64}#{file_name}"
    type = mime.split('/').first

    case type
    when 'image' || 'video'
        File.open("./public/uploads/#{type}s/#{filename}", 'wb') do |f|
            f.write(file.read)
        end
    else
        File.open("./public/uploads/files/#{filename}", 'wb') do |f|
            f.write(file.read)
        end
    end

    return filename
end
```

end

Here is part of the code from the _spec file to test :

```
context "when the file is uploaded" do
        it "should get the mime type" do

        end
        it "should get the filename" do

        end
        it "should save in local dir" do

        end
    end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What file attachment library are you using? Paperclip? CarrierWave? The testing technique you choose may depend on the library.

Comment: Have you tried to use [Rack::Test::UploadedFile](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/master/Rack/Test/UploadedFile). I can see you are using `Rack::Mime` for mime-types, I think, this could help.

Comment: Actually, I don't use any library and we are asked to do it with RSpec only. but, for Rack::Mime I used it because I found it on SO too, and I think I can use it in the helper without having to install it.

For now, I know a little about how to test it using a stub starting from small steps first with the help of friends, but I will leave this post alone maybe there is a better alternative.